# Interpretação de um algoritmo

Tags: algoritmo, pseudocódigo

Tenho que resolver um problema com o seguinte enunciado:

> ## As casas daquela rua
>
> ### Contexto
>
> Uma programadora de computadores mora em uma rua com casas **apenas em um dos lados**. As casas nessa rua são numeradas **sequencialmente** começando do número 1 (um). Todo dia a programadora sai de casa para passear e, escolhendo aleatoriamente uma direção, direita ou esquerda, vai até o fim da rua e volta. Um dia ela resolveu somar os números das casas pelas quais ela passava na ida e na volta, excluindo a sua própria casa. No outro dia ela tomou a outra direção e também somou os números das casas pelas quais ela passava, na ida e na volta, excluindo a própria casa. Para sua surpresa as somas foram iguais.
>
> ### Descrição
>
> Escreva um programa que imprima pares de números inteiros e positivos, o primeiro representando o número de uma casa e o segundo representando a quantidade de casas na rua, de tal forma que a propriedade observada pela programadora ocorra. Por exemplo, o primeiro par de números com essa propriedade é 6 e 8. Isto é, se a programadora mora na casa 6 em uma rua que tem 8 casas numeradas sequencialmente, então a soma das casas no caminho de ida e volta até o fim da rua será o mesmo nas duas direções. O segundo par com essa propriedade será 35 e 49.

Não percebi ainda a "matemática" e/ou relação por trás dessas casas da rua. Por exemplo: o primeiro par é 6 e 8, o segundo é 35 e 49. Qual a relação entre eles? Alguém poderia me explicar ou criar um modelo simples em pseudocódigo pra que eu tenha uma ideia?

Comment: Acho que a pergunta está mais clara agora ;)

Comment: Curiosa pergunta. Eu acho que a pergunta é bem objetiva, não pede opinião, é clara no que está perguntando, não é tão ampla assim, me parece fazer parte do nosso foco e certamente não não é duplicada. Porque eu ainda acho ela ruim? Será que é porque o OP não fez nada e quer pronto? Nem sei se é o caso. Mas se for, é questão de negativar e não fechar.

Comment: Não quero nada pronto. Disse apenas que não entendi o comando do problema, sendo assim não estou conseguindo fazer isso em código.

Comment: Editei a pergunta incluindo a parte principal do enunciado aqui no site mesmo. Assim fica mais fácil entender do que você está falando.

Comment: Bem melhor assim, obrigado!

Comment: @Lucas tomei a liberdade de mudar um pouco mais sua pergunta, pois a tag `c` não parecia ser relevante para ela. Também troquei "portugol" por "pseudocódigo", nem todo mundo sabe o que é portugol, acho que terá mais chances se ficar assim, entretanto se preferir pode desfazer as mudanças

Comment: Está ótimo assim. Obrigado!

Comment: Você fala em Portugol mas usou a *tag* de C. Isto não ficou claro do que você precisa. O pessoal acha que não está claro o que você quer. Você conseguiria dar mais informações do que deseja ou tentar explicar melhor o que precisa? Eu até entendi. Algumas pessoas talvez achem que você não se esforçou nada antes de postar alguma coisa aqui e quer tudo pronto. Se não é isto, poderia postar o que você entendeu do enunciado, o que você já conseguiu fazer mesmo que errado?

Comment: Desculpem qualquer coisa, é a primeira vez que faço uma pergunta aqui. Bem, não fiz nada justamente porque não entendi o que é para fazer. Não percebi ainda a "matemática" e/ou relação por trás dessas casas da rua. Por exemplo: o primeiro par é 6 e 8, o segundo é 35 e 49. Qual a relação entre eles? Não entendi.

Comment: Bom, a assistência pra melhorar a pergunta tá grande! Só não sei se o título precisa do "em C" c/c @NULL

Comment: @brasofilo estado de "carinho" tomando conta do povo, rsrs

Answer (score 5):

Como indicado no exemplo: (6,8)

A programadora mora na casa 6 de 8, logo:

//Direita:

```
{7,8} -> 7 + 8 = 15
```

Esquerda:

```
{1,2,3,4,5} -> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

## PseudoCódigo

```js
Inteiro esquerda = 0
Inteiro direita = 0 
//Direita
Para i = numeroCasaProgramadora faça:
     Se i < UltimaCasa Então:
        direita + = 1
     i + = 1
//esquerda
Para i = numeroCasaProgramadora faça:
     Se i > 0 Entao:
        esquera + = 1
     i - = 1    
Se esquerda == direita Então:
   Imprime "O par " + numeroCasaProgramadora + " e " + UltimaCasa + "é válido"
```

Comment: Agora entendi. Vou tentar criar um algoritmo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Lucas você pode postar o que conseguir fazer depois de entender para ajudar outras pessoas também.

Comment: @bigown Ok! Se der tudo certo, amanhã posto o resultado aqui. Obrigado por tudo ;)